# Java object method for Python's __int__():

Tags: java, python, methods, int

I'm trying to learn Java off of my existing Python knowledge. I understand that a Java object can have a `toString()` method in the same way that a Python object would have a `__str__()` method, but I don't know how to translate Python's  `__int__()` in the same way.

Here would be the Python equivalent of the code I'm trying to translate to Java:

```py
class Robot:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __int__(self):
        return 12

print(int(Robot())) # Should print 12.
```

Comment: Create a `toInt()` method.

Comment: There is no equivalent. You could add a `static` method to `Robot` and then statically import it?

Comment: Okay, that's what I had anticipated.

Comment: Is there a reason that there isn't an equivalent? @BoristheSpider

Comment: Java doesn't have "magic" methods that map to language functionality - it's a language choice. For a reason, you'd need to need to ask James Gosling - my guess is that because Java was designed to be the epitome of a simple lanuage it was decided that adding such magic would detract from this goal.

Comment: Does the `__init__(self) pass` means that is not possible to instantiate the `Robot` without argument?

Comment: @zlakad no. This is just the (rather ugly) way to write an instance method - you need to take `self` as an argument. The same is true for the ctor - it allows you to assign values to instance variables; for example `self.foo = 10`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, oh, O.K. - thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to have the `__init__`, actually, but it's become convention for me to have one. @zlakad

Comment: It's certainly not neccessary if you just call `pass` - but it's a fair convention. Maybe people add the empty ctor in Java too.

Comment: @JordanMann, I understand it now... Unfortunately, I don't have the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__int__` method in Python allows for a `class` to plug into the `int()` functionality built into the language - to "parse" an instance of an arbitrary `class` to an `int`.

There is not an equivalent in Java, but you could create a similar-looking construct. It would require you to be explicit.

```
public class Robot {
    private int serial;

    //ctor, getters, setters etc etc

    public int toInt() {
        return serial;
    }

    public static int toInt(Robot robot) {
        return robot.toInt();
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like

```
//some class, synax elided

import static com.pkg.Robot.toInt;

System.out.println(toInt(new Robot()));
```

As there is no `int()` functionality in Java, this doesn't really give you much over:

```
System.out.println(new Robot().toInt());
```

Or even the much more clear:

```
System.out.println(new Robot().getSerial());
```

---

If you want something more generic, you could create an `interface`:

```
public interface Intable {

    int toInt();

}
```

Then you could `implements` the `Interface` in classes that you think should be able to turn themselves into an `int`.